# False evaluation in a choice resulting in state machine being paused

Tags: java, spring-statemachine

The state machine pauses at the choice state when the evaluation inside the choice state returns false, instead of moving to the next state.

Code below:

States definition:

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<String, String>
states)  throws Exception {
    states
    .withStates()
    .initial("init")
    .choice("S1Choice")
    .state("S1")
    .choice("S2Choice")
    .state("S2")
    .choice("S3Choice")
    .state("S3")
    .state("end");
}
```

Transitions/Choice/Action:

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
    .withExternal()
    .source("init")
    .target("S1Choice")
    .event("start")
    .and()
    .withChoice()
    .source("S1Choice")
    .first("S1", new Guard<String, String>() {

        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            System.out.println("In s1 choice");
            /*Map<Object, Object> map = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            return !map.containsKey("S1done");*/
            return false;
        }
    })
    .last("S2Choice")
    .and()
    .withLocal()
    .source("S1")
    .target("S2Choice")
    .action(new Action<String, String>() {

        public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            Map<Object, Object> map = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            System.out.println("Executing s1");
            map.put("S1done", Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    })
    .and()
    .withChoice()
    .source("S2Choice")
    .first("S2", new Guard<String, String>() {

        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            System.out.println("In s2 choice");
            Map<Object, Object> map = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            return !map.containsKey("S2done");
        }
    })
    .last("S3Choice")
    .and()
    .withLocal()
    .source("S2")
    .target("S3Choice")
    .action(new Action<String, String>() {

        public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            Map<Object, Object> map = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            System.out.println("Executing s2");
            map.put("S2done", Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    })
    .and()
    .withChoice()
    .source("S3Choice")
    .first("S3", new Guard<String, String>() {

        public boolean evaluate(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            System.out.println("In s3 choice");
            Map<Object, Object> map = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            return !map.containsKey("S3done");
        }
    })
    .last("end")
    .and()
    .withLocal()
    .source("S3")
    .target("end")
    .and()
    .withLocal()
    .source("end")
    .target("init");
}
```

The main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TasksConfig.class);
    
    StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine = context.getBean(StateMachine.class);
    stateMachine.start();
    stateMachine.getExtendedState().getVariables().put("S1done", Boolean.TRUE);
    
    stateMachine.sendEvent("start");
    //stateMachine.stop();
}
```

The following is the sample from the output captured:

> Work item state changed to init
>
> INFO: started S2 S1 end init S3 S1Choice S3Choice S2Choice  / init /
>
> In s1 choice

As you can see, it stalls at state -"s1 choice" instead of moving to the new state -"s2 choice".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using 1.0.x which have issues with linked pseudostates(workaround is to put normal state between those choices). These are fixed in 1.1.x(1.1.0 is released next week).

Comment: Yes. After upgrading the version, it is working fine!! Thanks!!